# Posting a question automatically made me join a SE site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, android-tablet-app

I just posted a question on a site I wasn't a member of. Apparently it automatically joined me to that site, and I got the association bonus right away, so I know I wasn't a member of that site before.

I used the mobile SE app, and was never warned or alerted that posting a question would join me to the site. On the web, I have to specifically click for approval to join my profile to a SE site. Can the mobile app be changed to at least warn a user that posting a question will join their account to that site?

The comments have asked if the web/desktop site does the same thing. I don't know, but if it does (an account joining a site when posting a question) it should also warn the account holder about joining the site, or let the account post as an anonymous user. I shouldn't be forced to join my account to a SE site just to post a question.

Samsung Tab S3, app version 1.0.95

Comment: Just to be clear here, on the desktop site, if you attempt to post a question without joining the site, it posts as a newly-created unregistered account?

Comment: @Sonic I'm not sure, I don't think I've ever posted without joining, on the desktop side

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is if the same behavior occurs in the desktop site, it should be replicated in the app.

Comment: If it's the same on the desktop site, then i think it should still warn about joining a site before posting

Comment: @Sonic on the desktop you get to choose: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUeRY.png. Since the app **can't be used without being logged in**, it's different.

Comment: What is wrong with you having an account?

Comment: @Zani Nothing wrong with having my profile associated with a site, I'd just want a notification that it is going to happen. That is my feature request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design.

The Stack Exchange API both requires an access token to create questions and [stipulates the following](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question) on that route:

> Stack Exchange sites take question quality seriously, and many checks are run on the actual websites that can require various user actions be taken. In the API, any "low quality" checks that are triggered cause the write request to fail. This includes situations where a CAPTCHA or guidance text would be displayed on the websites.

What this means in practice is you need to be a member of that site in good standing to post a question, hence the joining of the site.

As far as why you automatically joined, that was a decision made years ago that I don't remember all the details of.  But the logic is, if you draft a question, you're invested in the site and it makes sense to automatically join you rather than prompt you to join after you already typed out a question.  Things like voting, on the other hand, are very low commitment so prompting to join explicitly makes more sense.

The idea of having a banner or some other indicator on the form saying something like, *"You are not a member of {siteName}; you will automatically join when you post,"* has merit but the apps aren't currently under active development so there's no timetable as to when something like that could be implemented.